Functional From to Approximate Volatility Surface
I have a finite difference pricing model and would like to factor in a volatility surface for each underlying equity. However, I have limited data. Essentially I'm just pulling a few implied volatilities from Bloomberg for each underlying equity. As such, I would like to postulate a functional form and simply fit it to my data. I was thinking of something like
$$
\sigma(S_t/K, t) =  \alpha + \beta \exp(-\gamma S_t/K) - \delta t.
$$
I'm not familiar with any sort of theory for the functional form, so I don't know if this is the right approach.

Directly interpolating carries risk of arbitrage

@Arshdeep Yeah, a functional form probably also invites arbitrage. However, they're probably both better than a constant volatility assumption.

What about Gatheral's SVI arbitrage-free implied volatility parameterization?

@Kevin Maybe. I should read the paper.
